# Capture the value of JSP Expression Language variable into a java variable

Tags: java, jsp, el

is it possible to capture the value of JSP Expression Language variable into a java variable in a jsp page?

Eg: I have a variable ${error.type} and i want to capture the value of ${error.type} into a java variable, say something like this: `String errortype = ${error.type}` (I know this isn't possible) Is there anyway for doing this?
Actually I want to check if `${error.type}` is null or not, if there is any value available I will show success message else an error message.
Thanks I'm new to java and JSP :)

---

Update:
I tried this code

```
 <c:choose>
     <c:when test="${not empty error.type}"> 
        test error message    
     </c:when>     
     <c:when test="${empty error.type}">
         test success message     
     </c:when> 
 </c:choose>
```

But now both the text are displayed simultaneously irrespective of empty or not! 
Even i tried `${errors.errors ? "some text when true" : "some text when false"}` and guess what, every time i'm getting "some text when false" printed in browser though the value is getting initialized correctly. any idea why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Actually I want to check if ${error.type} is null or not, if there is any value available I will show success message else an error message

You're looking for `${empty error.type}` in order to know if `error.getType()` is `null`:

```html
<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${not empty error.type}">
        ${error.message}
    </c:when>
    <c:when test="${empty error.type}">
        <!-- show your valid message -->
    </c:when>
</c:choose>
```

Comment: hi, thanks. i tried your code. but it's not working. 
This is the one i used:
`<c:choose>
    <c:when test="${not empty error.type}">
        test error message
    </c:when>
    <c:when test="${empty error.type}">
        test success message
    </c:when>
</c:choose>`
But i get both the text outputs! any idea why?

Comment: Before the `<c:choose>` add `${empty error.type} <br />` to check if it's empty or not. By the way you comment it, you're getting a very odd result.

Comment: yeah, I'm getting true and false for empty and non-empty returns. still the texts are getting printed in both the cases simultaneously!

Comment: Edit your question and add four dashes `----`, then **add** your current code and explain your new problem, do not delete the previous content.

Comment: Hi, i figured it out. i didn'd add <%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %> in the beginning of the jsp page. I didn't know we need to initialize it:) now it's working fine! thanks @luiggi mendoza

Comment: @Ganesh so the problem was that you weren't using JSTL. Glad to know you fixed it. Remember to mark the post that helped you most as the answer.

Comment: why did i get a negative point here? :/ anyway thanks for your help :)

Comment: @Ganesh probably by a person who doesn't understand the problem.

Answer (score 0):

i figured it out. i didn'd add `<%@taglib uri="java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"; prefix="c" %>` in the beginning of the jsp page. I didn't know we need to initialize it:) Anyway now it's working fine! thanks